# Spring Boot: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I was running a Spring Boot program and at first everything went fine. But after I hit `ctrl + c` and stopped the program, I restart the program and met the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

My program is a jar file, so I start it with `java -jar myJar`, and stop it by `ctrl + c`.

At first I thought this was because port 8080 was used. But when I tried the following commands I found there was nothing running on port 8080,

```
lsof -i:8080 # shows nothing
sudo lsof -i tcp:8000 # shows nothing
```

So I think there's no process running on port 8080 but why spring gives me that error?

I've tried another port 8081 and met the same problem again. But when I use `server.port=0`, it works. Can anyone give some suggestions on what to do? Thanks so much!!

Comment: can you execute **netstat -an|grep 8080**, the closed socket may have the state of **TIME_WAIT** etc...

Comment: Thanks for the info! I did see the TIME_WAIT state after I shut down the program. But after a while, when I typed this command again I got nothing. I thought that might be because the port is no longer in TIME_WAIT state so I started the program again. But got the same error.

Comment: it is weird, if you type the command  and the result is nothing, i think the port will no long be occupied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meet with similar issue when the web server visit is busy, so your server socket may have **TIME_WAIT** state, in this case the tomcat-embeded-server in spring boot can't bind this port because **SO_REUSEADDR** is not set to true
[image]

so my solution is to use **Jetty** in spring boot, you can change your **pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure, does that mean I only need to use Jetty and the `SO_REUSEADDR` will be set to true automatically?

Comment: yes, in jetty, the default value of SO_REUSEADDR is **true**

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you press **ctrl+c** when tomcat is running. This will turn the port to waiting. Firstly freeing up state by using this command: **fuser 8080 -k** then run the program again.

Comment: I got this after typing `fuser 8080 -k` : unknown option k. And when I typed `fuser 8080 -u` I was told /usr/bin/fuser: '8080' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I experience the similar issue when i was using ServerSocketIO. Problem in my code was, where Thread.sleep was used just after server.start(). So in ideal case if you just inject the ServerSocketIO bean and invoke the start method on it, Tomcat server will server the incoming request. handling of socket shutdown needs to be handled gracefully though in case of application crash or something...